# Keep getting "Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported"

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my project I have a (horizontal) FlatList that I want to trigger a function when a new page is visible. I've understood that I need to specify viewabilityConfig and onViewableItemsChanged. However, when I do I keep getting this error msg: "Changing onViewableItemsChanged on the fly is not supported".

I'm a newbie, so looking at the other posts about the same error didnt make me any smarter.

Any ideas?

```
const DATA = [
  20201202 = {
    id: "20201202",
    data: day1,
  },
  2020120 = {
    id: "2020120",
    data: day2,
  },
  20201204 = {
    id: "20201204",
    data: day3,
  },
]; */

const LiveScreen = (props, { navigation }) => {
  const FlatListItem = ({ title }) => (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title.day}</Text>
    </View>
  );

  // FLATLIST

  const renderFlatList = ({ item }) => <FlatListItem title={item} />;


  

  // VIEWABILITY
  const viewabilityConfig = {
    waitForInteraction: true,
    // At least one of the viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold or itemVisiblePercentThreshold is required.
    viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95,
    itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 75,
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#F4F5F5" }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>

        <SafeAreaView>
          <FlatList
            horizontal
            pagingEnabled
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={renderFlatList}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            initialScrollIndex={5}
            viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
            onViewableItemsChanged={(viewableItems, changed) => {
              console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
              console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
            }}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});

export default LiveScreen;
```

I have removed the excess code..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but the issue isn't the `viewabilityConfig`, it's the `onViewableItemsChanged`.

In a function component, you need to separate out the handler for `onViewableItemsChanged` and place it in a ref like so:

```js
const handleViewableItemsChanged = useRef(({viewableItems, changed})=>{
    console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
    console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed)
});

<FlatList
    ...
    viewabilityConfig={viewabilityConfig}
    onViewableItemsChanged={handleViewableItemsChanged.current}
/>
```

The same effect can be done with a `useCallback` hook with an empty dependency array, but this way is a bit more clean.

Answer (score 0):

viewabilityConfig needs to be done in the **constructor** to avoid this error.

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)

  this.viewabilityConfig = {
      waitForInteraction: true,
      // At least one of the viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold or itemVisiblePercentThreshold is required.
      viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95,
      itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 75,
  }
}
<FlatList
    viewabilityConfig={this.viewabilityConfig}
  ...
/>
```

For functional components, it needs to be done with **Ref** hook.

```
const viewabilityConfig = useRef({
  waitForInteraction: true,
      // At least one of the viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold or itemVisiblePercentThreshold is required.
      viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 95,
      itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 75,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In 2023 with react-native version `0.71.2`, the following code seems to work better.

```js
const viewabilityConfig = {viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 50};

const onViewableItemsChanged = ({viewableItems, changed}) => {
  console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
  console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
};

const handleViewableItemsChanged = useRef([
  {viewabilityConfig, onViewableItemsChanged}
]);

<FlatList
  ...
  viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={handleViewableItemsChanged.current}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that `onViewableItemsChanged` [does not support re-creating the function passed to it during the component's life-cycle](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/30171). Defining the function in-line means that it's re-created on every render.

Because of this, you need to memoize the function you pass to `onViewableItemsChanged`. A common way to do this is with `useCallback` *with an empty dependency array*.

```
const myHandler = useCallback(({viewableItems, changed}) => {
  console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
  console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
}, 
[]) // NOTE the *empty* dependency array; if you pass in dependencies and one changes, the function will re-create and trigger the error.

...
<Flatlist 
   ...
   onViewableItemsChanged={myHandler}
/>
```

A full discussion of this subject can be found [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-component-visibility-sensor-react-native/).

**Note** that this error will appear frequently during development of a component utilising `onViewableItemsChanged`, because, in development, [React throws away the cache when you edit a component's file](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#caveats), and thus `Flatlist` will think you've re-created the function in `onViewableItemsChanged`. This is not actually a problem (beyond being annoying) - just save the file again and the error will go away.